# Why when I run the ggttest there is an error?

Tags: r, t-test

When I run the t-test for a numeric and a dichotomous variable there in no problem and I can see the results. The problem is when I run the ggttest of the same t-test. There is an error and says that one of my variable is not found. I do not why that happens. The aml dataset I used is from package boot. Below you can see the code:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kuaA.png

```
library(gginference)
time_group.test16537 = t.test(formula = time~group,
                              data = aml,
                              alternative = "two.sided",
                              paired = FALSE,
                              var.equal = FALSE,
                              conf.level = 0.95)
    time_group.test16537


    ggttest(time_group.test16537,
            colaccept="lightsteelblue1", 
            colreject="gray84", 
            colstat="navyblue")
```

Comment: Hi @Katerina, it's a good question. I can see you use aml from package boot. Unfortunately people cannot reproduce your error with an image. Do you mind writing the two lines of code as part of your question, and also the libraries used?

Comment: @StupidWolf thank you very much for your comment. I am new to this forum, so I do not know very well how to write down correctly the questions.

Comment: Cool @Katerina, yeah see the answer below. It's some weird bug in the package.. The fix below should give you the plot

Comment: @StupidWolf everything worked out well. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes with these lines of code in ggttest:

```
datnames <- strsplit(t$data.name, splitter)
len1 <- length(eval(parse(text = datnames[[1]][1])))
len2 <- length(eval(parse(text = datnames[[1]][2])))
```

It tries to find the len of group and time, but it doesn't see that it came from a data.frame. Pretty bad bug...

For your situation, supposedly you have less than 30 in each group and it plots a t-distribution, so do:

```
library(gginference)
library(boot)
gginference:::normt(t.test(time~group,data=aml),
colaccept = "lightsteelblue1",colreject = "grey84", 
colstat = "navyblue")
```

[image]

Comment: Or call `t.test` using `t.test(aml$time ~ aml$group)`.

Comment: yeah @Axeman that's done in the vignette.. just not very convinced ggttest is properly written..

Comment: With bug report [here](https://github.com/okgreece/gginference/issues/1).

Comment: No problem, you did the hard part.

Answer (score 0):

`t.test` doesn't store your data in the output so there is no way that you could extract the data from the list of the output of `t.test`.

The only way to use formula is:

```
library(gginference)
t_test <- t.test(questionnaire$pulse ~ questionnaire$gender)
ggttest(t_test)
```

Original answer here: [How to extract the dataset from an "htest" object when using formula in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61434785/how-to-extract-the-dataset-from-an-htest-object-when-using-formula-in-r)