# How to extract the dataset from an "htest" object when using formula in r

Tags: r, hypothesis-test

The question is how to extract the dataset from an "htest" object when using formula.
For example,

```
library(gginference)
t_test <- t.test(formula = pulse~ gender,  
             data=questionnaire)
t_test$data.name
```

returns

```
[1] "pulse by gender"
```

Is there a way to extract the dataset (in this case "questionnaire")?

Comment: Is your ultimate goal to use the `t_test` object in `ggttest`?

Comment: Yes, that's the goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way that you could extract the data from the list of the output of t.test(). The code for the components of the output of t.test() is this:

```
rval <- list(statistic = tstat, parameter = df, p.value = pval,
           conf.int = cint, estimate = estimate, null.value = mu,
           alternative = alternative,
           method = method, data.name = dname)
    class(rval) <- "htest"
```

You can see that the list of the output of t.test() does not include the variables.

Answer (score 2):

Mohanasundaram answers the OP's specific question. `t.test` doesn't store your data in the output so you can't retrieve it.

However, via the OP's comment, if the goal is to use this in `ggttest` to visualize, there are two options.

First, `ggttest` is expecting the that you didn't use the formula syntax, and instead you  directly subset your dataframe (via `$`). This is because it expects the `t_test$data.name` output to look something like this: `"questionnaire$pulse by questionnaire$gender"` The quickest approach would be to not use formulas, if possible:

```
library(gginference)

t_test <- t.test(questionnaire$pulse ~ questionnaire$gender)

ggttest(t_test) #should give correct output
```

If for some reason you MUST use a formula, you can manually change `t_test$data.name` to match what `ggttest` is expecting:

```
t_test <- t.test(formula = pulse~ gender,  
             data=questionnaire)

t_test$data.name <- "questionnaire$pulse by questionnaire$gender"

ggttest(t_test)
```